# What's the best method to show how many enquiries are made for each item per week?

Tags: design, interface, data, users

Say, I've a website that sells 350 different types of pillows from all over the world.

Each week, there would be X number of people enquiring about the different pillows, and I would log the enquiries into my system.

Now, I want to show visually how many **enquiries** are made for **each pillow**, every **week**.

This is what I thought of: [image]

Looks ok? Or is there a better and cooler way? :)

Tks!

Comment: "Cool" doesn't necessarily tell me what I need to know better. If I'm hear just to get my weekly numbers a table does the job quickly and very effectively.

Comment: What do you do with the weekly numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to UXSE.

This is a good approch. 
But I have something different.

Added one new feature hope you like it.

Refer image:

[image]

Comment: Tks a lot! That's a beautiful cool feature! :-)

Comment: Welcome Bro! glad you like it.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you're interested in weekly tallies so you can compare them with each other. And clicking between single-week views isn't good for that. In that case, you'll probably want to show your info in ways that show longer periods of time. Maybe graph inquiries over time for the X most-popular pillows. And another for pillows of lowest interest?

And since you have so many products, you might want to let users export the data to Excel so they can crunch the data in ways that suit their own particular needs.

Comment: exporting to CSV should be sufficient for Excel users as well as Spotfire, QlickView, Numbers, Calc, whatever... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I attach 2 options to display the information which you want. 
This is my idea and this is wire-frame only so don't consider it as design.
I commented necessary information so please read it carefully. I hope you will have clear idea that what I am trying to explain.

Images shown below are just for the example purpose.

These are the screens :

[image: Grid View]
[image: List View]

Comment: Hi, tks a lot. What I don't understand is, for that Week picker control at the upper-left of your diagrams, how is the control UI going to look like? I've seen calendar controls that allows only the user to select one day, not one chunk of week. Tks! :-)

Comment: In that case you can give facility to select multiple days in calendar or you have to customize the calendar as per your requirement that display calendar by weeks. Because with multiple selection option user might select more than 7 days then it will be out of scope.